# Getting Error when retrieving an xlsx file from sharepoint using SPFile.openbinary();

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, httpresponse

I am using the below code to retrieve the files from sharepoint to byte[].

> SPFile file = currentWeb.GetFile(item);
>
> byte[] data = (byte[])file.OpenBinary();

I am getting the below exception, when i am retrieving xlsx files from sharepoint:

**Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack**

Can any one have an idea about it.........?

Comment: Are you sure the error occurrs on one of these two lines?